# How do I debug this question? Extracting the value out the dictionary

Tags: python

```
data = {
    'Jeremy':73284, 
    'Hansel':8784.3, 
    'Uee':9480938.2, 
    'Seolhyun':984958.3, 
    'Ketsuno Ana':24131, 
    'Trump':45789
}

for key, value in data.items():
    all_salary = data[value][0] + data [value][1] + data[value][2] + data[value][3] + data[value][4] + data[value][5]

average = all_salary / len[data]
print("The_average_networth is $" + str(average))
```

How do I add all the values of the numbers in the list into `all_salary`?

Comment: just use `sum(data.values())`

Comment: does he want all salaty = sum(v[i] for i, v in enumerate(data.values())?

Comment: If you search in your browser for "Python access dict", you'll find references that can explain this much better than we can manage here.  You have confused and combined multiple methods of accessing a structure.

Answer (score 0):

`value` is the value of the current element in the `for` loop, it's not a dictionary key, so `data[value]` is not right.. And your dictionary elements are not arrays, so it makes no sense to use `[0]`, `[1]`, etc.

In your loop you just need to add `value` to the `all_salary` variable, which you should initialize before the loop. You can also use `data.values()` to loop over just the values, since you're not using the keys.

```
all_salary = 0
for value in data.values():
    all_salary += value
```

There's also a built-in `sum()` function that will do the loop for you:

```
all_salary = sum(data.values())
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside `for` loop you have `value` for single person which you have to add to `all_salary`. You can use `print()` to see it.

```
all_salary = 0  # value at start to use +=

for key, value in data.items():
    #print(key, value)
    all_salary += value

average = all_salary / len[data]
```

But you can also write it shorter - if you know list comprehensions and `sum()`

```
all_salary = sum( [value for key, value in data.items()] )
```

or even without `[ ]`

```
all_salary = sum( value for key, value in data.items() )
```

or even simpler using `.values()` instead of `.items()`

```
all_salary = sum(data.values())
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
all_salary = 0
for key, value in data.items():
    all_salary += float(data[key])

average = all_salary / len(data)
```